# open camera and saving image using FileProvider not working. getting Error: W/ContextImpl: Failed to ensure directory:

Tags: android, camera

I used the following link to integrating camera in my app

> https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskScalePhoto

I followed each step but I'm getting following error whenever trying to take picture from the camera and a dialog also pops up showing "**Unfortunately, Camera has stopped.**"

**Error :**

> W/ContextImpl: Failed to ensure directory: /storage/**extSdCard**/Android/data/com.example.daf.formvalidator/files/Pictures
>
> E/OpenGLRenderer: SFEffectCache:clear(), mSize = 0

What strange to me is that the following code(taken from above link) returns "/emulated/0" in the value of storageDir
and above error shows "extSdCard"

> // returns
> /storage/**emulated/0**/Android/data/com.example.daf.formvalidator/files/Pictures/
>
> ```
> File storageDir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
> ```

**What do I want?**

-open camera app.

-store taken picture to **app's private storage** as mentioned in the link.

-want to use FileProvider

I also tried with setting flags on the intent such as:

> takePictureIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

I'm not able to find the issue and spent almost 1 day finding the issue.
Please provide any kind of help. It would be appreciated.

**Why there is difference between "value of storageDir" and error message?**

If question is not clear please suggest...

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If You are using the example from google developers try to put Your file to custom dir:

```
String mCurrentPhotoPath;

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File externalStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File directory = new File(externalStorageDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + "/yourappname");
        //create directory if not exist
        if (!directory.isDirectory()) {
            directory.mkdirs();
        }
    File image = File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName,  /* prefix */
        ".jpg",         /* suffix */
        storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Comment: But I want image to be stored in apps' private area using FileProvider.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to:

> open camera app.
>
> store taken picture to app's private storage as mentioned in the link.
>
> want to use FileProvider

The first thing I want to mention is that the error you're posting isn't an error at all. It's a warning, and you should be able to just ignore it. I think that warning means that they can't tell if the directory is there or not (which has to do with the linking I'm gonna talk about in a second). Can you post the actual stack trace for your exception? It doesn't sound like this is your problem.

The next thing that's unclear from your post is that it sounds like you're confusing private storage and a SD card. By definition, the files on the SD card are not private storage. See here for a longer explanation of your options: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Specifically, you want to note that what you are doing is saving to a SD card, which is by definition not internal (or private) storage.

As far as the difference between "/storage/emulated/0/" and "/storage/sdcard/", they should both point to the same directory. The short version is that since Android L, Android supports multiple users. "emulated/0" is a just a link to the main user's storage directory. What's interesting to me here is that usually when I hear 'emulated/0', it's in context of internal storage, but I don't see why it couldn't link to the SD card as well.